# Proving $\lVert A - B\rVert\le \max\{\lVert A\rVert,\lVert B\rVert\}$ $A,B$ positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given that $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite, how could one show:

$$
\lVert A-B\rVert\le \max\{\lVert A\rVert,\lVert B\rVert\}
$$

The norm is $\mathcal{l}_2$ induced operator norm.

I tried different ways to prove this to nothing. Any hint or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Your question and title ask two contradictory questions. I assume the title is your intended question, but please clarify.

Comment: What norm is $\lVert \bullet\rVert$ ? Is it this one? $$\lVert X\rVert :=\sup\{ v^tX^tXv\, :\, v^tv=1\}$$

Comment: does positive semidefinite include symmetric/hermitian?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $A,B$ are symmetric / hermitian.

Then, there exists some $u$ with $\|u\|=1$ such that $|u^H (A-B) u| = \|A-B\|$.
It follows
$$ u^H (A - B) u = u^H A u - \underbrace{u^H B u}_{\ge 0} \le u^H A u \le \|A\| $$
and 
$$ -u^H (A - B) u = u^H B u - \underbrace{u^H A u}_{\ge 0} \le u^H B u \le \|B\|. $$
Thus,
$$ \|A-B\| = | u^H (A-B) u | \le \max\{\|A\|, \|B\|\}. $$

**Notes:**

In fact, it is wrong if $A$ and $B$ are not symmetric / hermitian.
Consider
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = -B.$$
Then, $A + A^T = 0$ and $B + B^T = 0$. Thus they are both positive semidefinite. But $\|A-B\| = 2\|A\| > \|A\|$.

Comment: how do you show the existence of such a $u$ in the second line?

Comment: @kulaw: Eigenvalue decomposition. For hermitian matrix $M$ you have $\|M\|=|\lambda_\max(M)|$ where $\lambda_\max(M)$ denotes the absolutely largest eigenvalue of $M$.

Comment: @user2511257. Thank you very much makes sense. To make sure I understand this... using eigenvalue decomposition $\Lambda= Q^TAQ$. where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues. Assume that the eigenvalues are ordered decreasing along the diagonal. Then the maximum eigenvalue corresponds to $q_1^TAq_1$ and then proceed as you showed. Is that right?

Comment: @kulaw: yes, then $\|A\| = \|Q\Lambda Q^T\| = \|\Lambda\| = \max_{i} |\lambda_i|$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes so much sense. I have accepted your answer.